# Volley failing multipart form data request

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartform-data

I am trying to send multipart data to a server, this data includes also some images.
So i extended `Request` in this way:

```
public class MultipartImageRequest extends Request<String> {

private MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

private static final String STRING_PART_NAME = "text";

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final ArrayList<Bitmap> mFiles = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<>();

public MultipartImageRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, ArrayList<Bitmap> files, HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFiles.addAll(files);
    mParams = params;

}

private void buildMultipartEntity()
{

    int i = 0;
    for(Bitmap image : mFiles) {

        /*Compress bitmap*/
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);

        entityBuilder.addPart("image_" + i, new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), "image_" + i));
        i++;

    }


    StringBuilder paramsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> paramIterator = mParams.entrySet().iterator();
    while (paramIterator.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry<String,String> entry = paramIterator.next();
       entityBuilder.addPart(entry.getKey(), new StringBody(entry.getValue(), ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT));

    }




}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8";
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{

    buildMultipartEntity();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try
    {
        entityBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8");
    return params;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response)
{
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

The problem is that if i set as a content type `application/json` it works and sends data to the server, but obviously the server gives me back an error `400` because it is expecting a multipart request, rather if i set the content type as `multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8` like in the code above `Volley` just doesn't send the request and gives me an error `500`.
I am using [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) to check my data and it confirms what i said above.
Also i am using a Rest Client and the request is working with it and on iphone too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on my own, it is important to pass a boundary to the request, otherwise the server will not be able to take our parameters.
It can be done replacing this code:

```
public MultipartImageRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, ArrayList<Bitmap> files, HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFiles.addAll(files);
    mParams = params;

}
```

with this one:

```
public MultipartImageRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, ArrayList<Bitmap> files, HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFiles.addAll(files);
    mParams = params;
    entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entityBuilder.setBoundary(BOUNDARY);
}
```

and remember to set the boundary string in your `Content-Type`:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY + "; charset=utf-8";
}


@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY + "; charset=utf-8");
    return params;
}
```

Comment: @AmitKumarKannaujiya you can set whatever you want, your boundary could be "blablabla" is just an arbitrary name

Comment: Does server guys need to know about the boundary ?

Comment: No it is not needed since you specify it in your headers.

Comment: can you check once this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605623/volley-failing-multipart-form-data-request/29668753?noredirect=1#comment52165682_29668753   is it same case with you or do you have any idea ?

Comment: @AmitKumarKannaujiya am i wrong or you just linked this discussion?

Comment: oh ,  check this  ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119687/multipart-image-request-with-json-params-in-single-call-using-volley-framework

Comment: please check once the  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119687/multipart-image-request-with-json-params-in-single-call-using-volley-framework