# Multipart Image Request with JSON params in Single Call using volley Framework

Tags: android, apache, android-volley, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I am sending multipart Post request in Volley along with the JSon params {as required by server } , but at server side null params are received .

In this request, I need to send Requested params in one part fist, and the image file in the next part .

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("appkey", Constants.REQUEST_API_KEY);
            params.put("LoginID",issueRequest.getUserName());
            params.put("device_id", issueRequest.getImei().toString());
            params.put("tokenID", AppSharedPreferance.getAppSharedPreferanceInstance(mContext).getToken(Constants.REQUEST_TOKEN, null));
            params.put("issueId", String.valueOf(mRequestIssueId));
            params.put("serverID", String.valueOf(mServerId));

        JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject();
        requestObj.put("ISSUE_DATA_KEY", new JSONObject(params));
```

I am requesting like :

```
PhotoMultipartRequest<JSONObject> photoMultipartRequest=null;

        photoMultipartRequest=new PhotoMultipartRequest<JSONObject>(url, requestObj.toString(), new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(IssueRequest.TAG, "inside Error");
                VolleyLog.d(Constants.REQUEST_ERROR, "Error had occured " + error.getCause());
            }
        }, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               Log.v(IssueRequest.TAG,"Responce -> Issue Attachments "+response);
                String status = null;
                int code=-1;
                try {
                     code = (int) response.getInt("error_code");
                    status = response.getString("response_string");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.v(IssueRequest.TAG, "code->" + code + "status->" + status + "Responce ->" + response.toString());

            }
        },
                new File(issue.getAttachmentPath().toString()));

        photoMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicyClass());
        Log.v(TAG, "Issue data " + photoMultipartRequest.toString());
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(photoMultipartRequest);
```

When i am printing the response object, it has **null** params .

```
{"response_string":"Invalid request.","error_code":"1","required_params":null}
```

My VolleyRequest Class :

```
public  class PhotoMultipartRequest<T> extends Request<T> {


private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
private static final String FILE_JSON_PART_NAME = "parms";

private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
private final Response.Listener<T> mListener;
private final File mImageFile;
protected Map<String, String> headers;
protected String params;
protected static final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";

public PhotoMultipartRequest(String url, ErrorListener errorListener, Listener<T> listener, File imageFile){
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mImageFile = imageFile;

    buildMultipartEntity();
}

public PhotoMultipartRequest(String url,String params, ErrorListener errorListener, Listener<T> listener, File imageFile){
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mImageFile = imageFile;
    this.params=params;

    try {
        buildMultipartEntity1();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

    if (headers == null
            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

    return headers;
}

private void buildMultipartEntity1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    mBuilder.addPart(FILE_JSON_PART_NAME, new StringBody(params));

    mBuilder.addBinaryBody(FILE_PART_NAME, mImageFile, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), mImageFile.getName());
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}

private void buildMultipartEntity(){


    mBuilder.addBinaryBody(FILE_PART_NAME, mImageFile, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), mImageFile.getName());
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType(){
    String contentTypeHeader = mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
    return contentTypeHeader;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream bos, building the multipart request.");
    }

    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{
    try {
        String result = null;
        result = new String( response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset( response.headers ) );
        return ( Response<T> ) Response.success( new JSONObject( result ), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response) );
    } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

I cannot find any clue of what went wrong. So, can anyone help me to correct my request class?

Comment: Post your server-side code plz

Comment: It not accessible to me :(

Comment: Can any one please check

Comment: Hi! I think you can try replace `mBuilder.addPart(FILE_JSON_PART_NAME, new StringBody(params));` by the following sample code `JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("Description", "Test Description");
    jsonBody.put("Author", "Test Author");
    jsonBody.put("Date", "2015/08/21");
    mBuilder.addTextBody(FILE_JSON_PART_NAME, jsonBody.toString(), ContentType.create("application/json"));`

Comment: @BNK   I had tried but it is not working .

Comment: I think you should contact the man who writes server app to check more

Comment: @BNK ohk , I will check with him .

Comment: @TheRedFox : Can you check this once ?

Comment: @TheRedFox : can you check this once ?

Comment: IMO, you can try to build your own web service to test